# Tableau Forecasting - Showing Actuals + Forecast Total

Tags: tableau-api, crosstab, forecasting

From what I've seen, if you take Tableau forecasting under the "analytics" pane, and try to convert the output into a table (instead of the normal line chart), the actual and forecast amounts are separated into 2 different row labels. Is it possible to combine the forecast and actuals to show a actuals + forecast number for the year that's automatically calculated WITHIN tableau after new sales data is added?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like this

[image]

You can refer to the Video in the link below:

http://tclive.tableau.com/Library/Video?vCode=BRK51584-3

Comment: I can't access the link you gave me but yes, that's what I'm looking for although in a table format - on the same line as right now tableau splits the forecast & actuals into 2 row labels.